# stop jQueryRotate plugin on mouseover on current position and continue on mouseout

Tags: jquery, animation, rotation, mouseover, mouseout

I am trying to stop a spinning wheel on the current position its in on mouse over using jQueryRotate plug in and continue animation rotating where it was stopped on mouse out,

I can't seem to make it work with the stop method which works on my custom animations

the code for the spinning wheel would be here on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73pXD/)

```
var angle = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        angle+=3;
    $("#carwheel").rotate(angle,{ easing:'easeInOutElastic'});

    $("#carwheel")
    .mouseover(function () { $(this).stop(); })
    .mouseout(function () { $(this).resume(); })

    },100);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Code will work for you,

```
var angle = 0;
var int;
rotateImage();

function rotateImage() {
    int = setInterval(function() {
        angle += 3;
        $("#image").rotate(angle);
    }, 50);
}
$("#image").mouseover(function() {
    clearInterval(int);
    //$(this).stop();
}).mouseout(function() {
    rotateImage();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/73pXD/2393/

Comment: Thanks man that worked

can you explain what you did 

what is that clearInterval

Comment: `clearInterval` clears the interval which set using `setInterval`. To do this interval variable should be global. `setInterval` call any function periodically and `clearInterval` will stop that.

Comment: @Marcos: hmm without accepting, upvotes just said that worked. Do you think people will answer your future questions anymore.

Comment: Sandmal Thanks Man , Sorry for the late reply it had been a while since i logged in here, i thought i had said thanks but i guess i did not write how i imagined, but thanks man , will say thanks next time, you can view the example of this at if you wan to see what the clear interval did http://www.modifiedarts.com